# Android how to listen to sync turned on in accounts and settings

Tags: android, settings, synchronization

My application has 2 automatic sync modes (all networks/just WiFi).

I want to listen for when the user turns on auto sync in the Android settings (NOT my applications setttings) and then set my automatic mode accordingly.

How can i listen for when a user turns on Sync in the Android Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is content provider where value of that check box is stored .

@Override

```
public boolean  [More ...] onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferences, Preference preference) {

    if (preference instanceof SyncStateCheckBoxPreference) {

        SyncStateCheckBoxPreference syncPref = (SyncStateCheckBoxPreference) preference;

        String authority = syncPref.getAuthority();

        Account account = syncPref.getAccount();

        boolean syncAutomatically = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account, authority);

        if (syncPref.isOneTimeSyncMode()) {

            requestOrCancelSync(account, authority, true);

        } else {

            boolean syncOn = syncPref.isChecked();

            boolean oldSyncState = syncAutomatically;

            if (syncOn != oldSyncState) {

                // if we're enabling sync, this will request a sync as well

                ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, syncOn);

                // if the master sync switch is off, the request above will

                // get dropped.  when the user clicks on this toggle,

                // we want to force the sync, however.

                if (!ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically() || !syncOn) {

                    requestOrCancelSync(account, authority, syncOn);


                }
            }
        }
```

This something where you need to do some extra work. Settings always saves every value to shared preference . you need to find that value from shared preference and register for that shared preference change listener. I don't know is it possible to listen for that sync check box or not.

Here is the link where u find that check box or switch preference where value are being saved. 
Analyze [First](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/settings/AccountPreference.java?av=f) [Second](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/settings/accounts/SyncSettings.java?av=f) links.

One more thing to note is , settings code saves some value in this tables .

**[First table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html)**

[**Second table**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)

**[Third table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)**